# Make Only Accessible to Feed URL on a WordPress Site

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering if it is possible to write a plugin which shows nothing but only let the visitor access the feed url. The admin page should be accessible by the administrator as well.

The background of this idea is that I've written a custom feed generator and implemented it in a WordPress site. Since the site is only for the feeds, I'd like to make the site invisible to the public except the feed outputs.

I'm aware that there are [Maintenance Mode](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=maintenance+mode) and [Members Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=members%20only) plugins. The problem is that the maintenance mode prohibits feed access and the member only mode bans general visitors.

So I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this. I'd like to avoid editing mod_rewrite because I'm planning to make it as a plugin if possible. If it is not realistic to do it without mod_rewrite, I will try editing mod_rewrite.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never want anything to render this could easily be fixed using the template_redirect hook. For example:

```
function stop_rendering() {
    exit;
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'stop_rendering');
```

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you don't want the theme to render? What about `/categories`, `/tags`, `/archives` etc.?

If that's all you want to do, you could just create a blank theme with the style.css (blank besides the theme info comment block) and the index.php template.

Comment: `you don't want the theme to render?` -  Exactly. I don't want anything to be rendered. `What about /categories, /tags, /archives etc.?` - No contents should be rendered in those pages also. `you could just create a blank theme with the style.css` - Using a theme was something I've totally forgotten about. It should be the answer. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, sometimes the obvious answers are the ones that escape us easiest. Take a look at plugins that re-direct to a mobile only theme -- you could model your plugin after the same technique, and redirect to a blank theme.