# Feed Only WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a theme which renders nothing but allows access to the feed url and the admin page. This is a continuation of this question: [Make Only Accessible to Feed URL on a WordPress Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960393/make-only-accessible-to-feed-url-on-a-wordpress-site).

I've created empty `style.css` with the comment header as follows.

**style.css**

```
/*
    Theme Name: Only Feeds
    Description: Renders only feeds.
    Version: 0.0.1
    Template: twentyeleven
*/
```

And created the following empty files under the theme directory.

**Added Files**

```
search.php
searchform.php
showcase.php
sidebar.php
sidebar-footer.php
sidebar-page.php
tag.php
single.php
style.css
404.php
archive.php
author.php
category.php
comments.php
content.php
content-aside.php
content-featured.php
content-gallery.php
content-image.php
content-intro.php
content-link.php
content-page.php
content-quote.php
content-single.php
content-status.php
footer.php
functions.php
header.php
image.php
index.php
page.php
```

It seems to be working so far but I noticed that when I forgot to create the empty `single.php`, navigation text appeared in a single page. That makes me concern if I'm missing something or not.

Also if Twenty-eleven gets updated and happens to add some files, will there be a page that outputs something?

Comment: I see now that someone already gave you my answer in that other thread. Nonetheless, it is the right one. In the other thread I also gave a different way of doing it, since it was more at home there, which would work a child theme such as the one you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only page you need is index.php and style.css, just don't create it as a child theme but as a stand alone theme. This will work because Wordpress automatically provides feeds, this functionality does not belong to any one theme.

Comment: I excluded the other files except `index.php` and removed the line, `Template: twentyeleven` in style.css. However, it still outputs the page contents when I access to a single page.

Comment: Ops, it might be due to the browser cache. I tried it again and now it works. Thanks you.